# JavaScript canvas: when clearing with context.clearRect, everything reapears on next draw

Tags: javascript, canvas

I got some lines drawn on my canvas. I want to clear it so that I can draw some new lines.
I use `context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`, just as everyone is suggesting. But when I draw some new lines, all the lines I've previously drawn reappear.
When using the `canvas.width = canvas.width` trick, it works as expected.

What am I missing?

Comment: Post the code that draws the lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably did not end your previous path. Make sure to call `ctx.beginPath()` before drawing your new lines.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
function draw()
{
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath(); // <-
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
  ctx.stroke();
}
function drawFaulty()
{
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.moveTo(100, 100);
  ctx.lineTo(200, 200);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas><br/>
<button onclick="draw()">Clear and Draw</button><br/>
<button onclick="drawFaulty()">Clear and Draw - Faulty</button>
```

Comment: I blame [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp).

Comment: Always blame w3schools.

Comment: This is old but saved my life!